# KIVY: Multiprocessing does nothing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy

I'm trying to display an animation while something else is done in the background and I have this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from threading import Thread
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.animation import Animation
import multiprocessing
import time

sm = ScreenManager()
Builder.load_string("""
<LoadingScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: loading_anim
            text: 'Hello'

<MainLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:

            text: 'world'
""")


class MainLayout(Screen):
    pass


class LoadingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        t = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.loading_anim)
        t.start()
        t.join()

    def loading_anim(self, *args):
        print('sleeping after starting animation')
        loading_anim = self.ids['loading_anim']
        anim = Animation(
            d=.7,
            opacity=1
        )
        anim += Animation(
            d=.7,
            opacity=.6
        )
        time.sleep(1)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(loading_anim)

        time.sleep(1)
        print('awake')

    def prepare_for_launch(self, *args):
        sm.switch_to(MainLayout(name='settings'))



class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(LoadingScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(MainLayout(name='settings'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

but it throws an error saying:

**"TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__"**

but if I don't use multiprocessing it works.
Replace

```
    def on_pre_enter(self):
    t = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.loading_anim)
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

with

```
    def on_pre_enter(self):
    self.loading_anim
```

and it works fine. (the fact that animation starts after sleeping is done is concerning me too as I initiate it before sleeping.)

Comment: The issue lies probably in joining the process. See the related posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959371/why-cant-this-python-multiprocessing-process-be-terminated-from-kivy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287104/why-kivy-doesnt-allow-multiprocessing-precess-to-terminate-in-python)

Comment: Unfortunately none of those answer my problem.

Comment: I could reproduce the error and added this issue on [github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6915).

Comment: I don't think you can animate an object in one process from another process. Try using `t = Thread(target=self.loading_anim)` to use a `Thread` instead of a `Process`.